# Jquery adding class to element on devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a responsive slider, which will have two different behaviours.

One for desktop.
One for Mobile.

The step are:

- Check if device mode is active and add class **Mobile**
- Check if desktop mode is active and add class **Desktop**

The issue I'm having code wise is:

- How can I add a class active to the `<li>` on click?
- How can I remove the class active to `<li>` if I click `close-btn` ?

  [Demo Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d2qgcexc/1/)

```js
//Check if device mode is active and add class Mobile 
mobileViewUpdate();
$(window).on('load, resize', mobileViewUpdate);

function mobileViewUpdate() {
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
  if (viewportWidth < 600) {
    $(".items").addClass("mobile");
    $(".mobile").removeClass("desktop");
  } else {

    $(".items").addClass("desktop");
    $(".mobile").removeClass("mobile");
    $(".mobile").removeClass("active");
  }
};
// Now add class active to li if parent has class Mobile 
$(".mobile li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  // remove classes from all

  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});

$(".close-btn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  $(this).find('li.active').removeClass('active')
});
```

```css
.items {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 5000px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.items li {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  /*background-color: rgba(228, 0, 59, 1);*/
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.items li .bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
}

.items li>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.items li>a .content {
  /*  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(228, 0, 59, 0.75));
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(228, 0, 59, 0.75));*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(100%) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.items li>a .content h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}


/*make bg on MOBILE personalized*/

.mobile {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.mobile li.active a .content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile li .content>span.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: -10px;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/master/black/svg/close.svg) no-repeat;
  mask: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/master/black/svg/close.svg) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 20px;
  mask-size: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  z-index: 3;
}


/*make bg on DESKTOP personalized*/

.desktop {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.desktop li .content>span.close-btn {
  display: none;
}

.desktop li:hover {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
  width: calc(320px + 40px);
  height: calc(320px + 40px);
}

.desktop li:hover a .content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transition-delay: .75s;
  transition-delay: .75s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix flex-auto py3">
  <ul class="items">
    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: You should look into media queries for handling desktop/mobile.

Comment: @Gerard I need a click event on mobile! and a close  Button

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/murbqgze/2/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't work because

1.( this is optional ) i think that your click functions should be included in the `mobileViewUpdate`  function

2.`close-btn` is a child ( is inside ) of `.mobile li` so when you click on it, you also click on `li` so you remove and add class in the same time

you should check ( when click on mobile li ) if the element you click is the close btn , and if it is, cancel the click . So when you click on `close-btn` the code won't interpret that you clicked on li also

3.in the `close-btn` click function you write `$(this).find('li.active').removeClass('active')` . find() only searches INSIDE the element . in this case, li is a parent of the `close-btn` , but not an immediate one, so you need to use `parents()` to find the `li.active`

see code below or jsfiddle [jsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d2qgcexc/6/)

```js
//Check if device mode is active and add class Mobile 
mobileViewUpdate();
$(window).on('load, resize', mobileViewUpdate);

function mobileViewUpdate() {
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
  if (viewportWidth < 600) {
    $(".items").addClass("mobile");
    $(".mobile").removeClass("desktop");
  } else {

    $(".items").addClass("desktop");
    $(".mobile").removeClass("mobile");
    $(".mobile").removeClass("active");
  }
};
// Now add class active to li if parent has class Mobile 
$(".mobile li").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  // remove classes from all
  if ($(e.target).is('.close-btn')) {

    return;
  }

  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
  $("li.active").not(this).removeClass("active")
});

$(".close-btn").click(function(e) {

  $(this).parents('li').removeClass("active")
});
```

```css
.items {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 5000px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.items li {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  /*background-color: rgba(228, 0, 59, 1);*/
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.items li .bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
}

.items li >a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.items li > a .content {
  /*  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(228, 0, 59, 0.75));
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(228, 0, 59, 0.75));*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(100%) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.items li >a .content h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}


/*make bg on MOBILE personalized*/

.mobile {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.mobile li.active a .content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.mobile li .content >span.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: -10px;
  -webkit-mask-size: 20px;
  mask-size: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: Red;
}


/*make bg on DESKTOP personalized*/

.desktop {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.desktop li .content >span.close-btn {
  display: none;
}

.desktop li:hover {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
  width: calc(320px + 40px);
  height: calc(320px + 40px);
}

.desktop li:hover a .content {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(0) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transition-delay: .75s;
  transition-delay: .75s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix flex-auto py3">
  <ul class="items">
    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="bg-img" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/320x320');"></div>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="content">
          <span class="close-btn">close btn</span>
          <h2>Slider item</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: almost exactly as I was doing in a fiddle - although i had click events in a document .ready

Comment: Almost there, as I have active lis still with the class Active.

Comment: when do you want to remove the `.active` class from `li` ? when you click on the `close-btn` ? and also when ?

Comment: I should have only one Active, and the Close- button, should remove the activeclass, almost there thanks:-)

Comment: ok. you need to add `$("li.active").not(this).removeClass("active")` in the `mobile li` click function . see here > https://fiddle.jshell.net/d2qgcexc/5/

Comment: glad i could help  :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144816/discussion-between-user3699998-and-mihai-t).

Comment: do you know why when I click (".close-btn") it removes all the classes I have on the li?

Comment: yes. it's because i forgot to write inside `removeClass()` 'active' . so change inside the close-btn click function with `removeClass('active') see here >https://fiddle.jshell.net/d2qgcexc/6/